# PrintWriter Loop to a Server

Tags: java, server, client, client-server, printwriter

Some background:  I'm beginning a computer science grad program (I've self-taught myself basically everything I know; zero academic CS experience) and an assignment early on is to create a client-server application that allows the client to upload or download text files from the server.

I'm working on the upload part, where I have the client read the text file line-by-line (with a while-loop) through a buffered reader, then send those lines through to the server, which then uses a PrintWriter and another while-loop to write those same lines in to a file.

I've printed into the console to test and I can confirm the client is passing along the correct output. 
I can also confirm the server is receiving that output and writes it correctly when printing to the console...except I'm not getting the "Upload Complete!" message when the loop is done. So, the loop seemingly doesn't end for some reason, so when printing to the file, I can't pull out of the loop, close the PrintWriter (and save the file) and tell the client the upload is done.

The result is, I'm seeing the file created where I want it, but there is no content.

EDIT: Got everything working.

Here's the client

```
try{
        //create socket
        Socket clientSocket = new Socket("192.168.1.114", 2006);

        //input stream & reader
        InputStream clientInputStream = clientSocket.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader clientReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientInputStream));

        //create output stream & writer
        OutputStream clientOutputStream = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
        PrintWriter clientWriter = new PrintWriter(clientOutputStream, true);

        //look for input from server and print it to the console
        String command = clientReader.readLine();
        System.out.println(command);

        //assign the user input as the next character, then send that character over the output stream
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String reply = in.next();
        clientWriter.println(reply);

        //Base conditional statements around what client wants to do
        //If choose download, client reads text file from server and writes to a file
        if(reply.equals("D") || reply.equals("d"))
        {
            //DOWNLOAD CODE STILL TO COME
            System.out.println("Client is reading from server and writing to file");
        }
        //If choose upload, client uploads and writes text file to server
        else if(reply.equals("U") || reply.equals("u"))
        {
            //Creates scanner looking for server "which file to upload (must be a .txt file, DO include file extension" prompt
            //Prints the prompt to the console
            Scanner serverUploadQuestion = new Scanner(clientReader);
            String serverUploadPrompt = serverUploadQuestion.nextLine();
            System.out.println(serverUploadPrompt);

            //Assigns the filename to the next user input, sends the name to server
            Scanner clientFileChoice = new Scanner(System.in);
            String fileToUpload = clientFileChoice.nextLine();
            clientWriter.println(fileToUpload);
            clientWriter.flush();

            //Reads the designated file and prints it to the server
            try{
            FileReader fileRead = new FileReader("C:/Users/Mike/Documents/" + fileToUpload);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fileRead);

            String line;
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                clientWriter.println(line);//test by printing to console
            }
            clientSocket.shutdownOutput();
            }catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe){System.out.println(fnfe.getMessage() + "The file was not found");}
        }


        //wait for final server response, and print its response in the console
        String result = clientReader.readLine();
        System.out.println(result);
        }catch(IOException e){System.out.println("Client at-end problem is " + e);}
    }
```

}

And the server

```
try{
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(2006);
        //establish socket and input/output readers
        Socket myS = ss.accept();
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(myS.getInputStream()));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(myS.getOutputStream(), true);

        //print a prompt to the client
        out.println("Enter 'u' to upload a file, 'd' to download a file");
        out.flush();

            String u = "U";
            String uu = "u";
            String d = "D";
            String dd = "d";
            String filename;
            String clientChoice = bf.readLine();

            //if the client chooses upload
            if (clientChoice.equals(u) || clientChoice.equals(uu))
            {
                //ask the client for the file name, assign it to a string variable
                out.println("Which file are you uploading (must be a .txt file, INCLUDE file extension in the name)?");
                filename = bf.readLine();

                try{
                //Create a file writer that will write the file
                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("c://Users/Mike/workspace/"+filename);

                //Create print writer
                PrintWriter fp = new PrintWriter(fw);

                //Print to the file each line coming in from the client
                String fileLine;
                while((fileLine = bf.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    fp.println(fileLine);
                }
                fp.close();
                out.println("Upload Complete!");
                //close the file printer
                }catch(IOException e){System.out.println("Server problem is " + e);}

            }
            //if client chooses download
            else if (clientChoice.equals(d) || clientChoice.equals(dd))
            {
                out.println("Downloaded file!");
            }
            //if client enters invalid input
            else if (!clientChoice.equals(u) && !clientChoice.equals(uu) && !clientChoice.equals(d) && !clientChoice.equals(dd))
            {
                out.println("Invalid prompt.  Please re-connect and try again.");
            }

        }catch(IOException e){System.out.println("Server at-end problem is " + e);}
}
```

}

Comment: In other words -- you are likely experiencing an exception and are completely ignoring it for some unknown reason (please do tell us why you are doing this). At least print out the stacktrace.

Comment: Also only close a writer/reader or stream after checking that it's not null.

Comment: Also, if you use try with resources, then you won't even have to explicitly close these things.

Comment: I added code to print for exceptions and didn't get anything, so it doesn't look like an exception.  I did the same for checking to see if it's null and am still running into the same problem.

Comment: Please show how you now check for exceptions in your code above. Also have you run this with a debugger?

Comment: Updated the code as suggested.  Still running into the same trouble.

Comment: Thanks for the update, and I've tried to format your code, especially improving your indentation (many of your blocks have no indentation whatsoever). Please strive to post only well formatted code so that we can read and understand it. It's in your best interest to put in this extra effort. As for your problem, your null check is wrong -- you check if `fp` is null before closing it. You don't try to read in from the `bf` once more as you're doing. Please fix this. As for the exception block, simplify it to `e. printStacktrace();`.

Comment: Also do a println to the console from within the while loop above as an extra precaution. Or better still (and again) run this in a debugger.

Comment: I'm printing to the console as well as to the printwriter.  The console output completely matches what it should be.  I'm still running into the same issue where the loop won't close.  I guess debugger it is.

Comment: You don't show in the code above any output to the console within your while loop. If you still need our help, a more complete [mcve] code post would help best. Please read the link on [mcve] and also on [sscce](http://sscce.org) to see what we need. Please ask for clarification if you don't understand anything in those links.

Comment: Updated again.  Sorry, I'm adding things on my own work in eclipse but not necessarily editing the source code on here right away.  Also, I apologize, as I'm still new to this whole coding world.  I've been in a formal CS environment for all of 3 weeks.  Before that, it was 9 years of broadcast journalism.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure (outside of not updating the code right away when saying "I tried...x" where I failed in the minimal, complete and verifiable requirements.  I provided the code and gave as much information as to what the issue was as I could reasonably communicate.  Perhaps I'm just purely incompetent, in which case I've made one hell of a career-change mistake.

Comment: You're doming along. What I'm looking for in a [mcve] is something that I can use as a nucleus of code that I can test, run, and modify. If you create something as close to a valid MCVE or SSCCE, it makes it much easier for others to help you, and because of this, it's far in your best interest to try to do this to the best of your abilities.

Comment: Some errors in your code -- look at [link](http://pastebin.com/R2pQKsk4) to see what I mean.

Comment: I tried the fix you suggested in the null test, but am still getting the same deal. Also have tried some socket input/output shutdown advice I got from another forum.  Still same thing.  I've posted my entire code for the client and server.  It's showing up with indentations on my end, but I'm sure that is not the case on your end.  I'm just not sure how to fix it, since it looks indented and formatted on my screen.

Comment: It's indented better than your first code posts. Look at your edit history and you'll see that the initial code was terrible. Let me take a look.

Comment: But as you know this code isn't close to being a [mcve]... ah well...

Comment: You're not closing/flushing all your important streams, and this can cause your problem. Read on this and fix it. You just need to close the outermost decorator, but it must be closed when done.

Comment: Good news.  I closed off the clientWriter after sending over all the text and that successfully allowed the server to write to the file and save it.

Comment: The only downside is, now for some reason the socket closes after this, so the client isn't getting back the "upload complete!" message. But my main concern has been taken care of, so there's that!

Comment: Yes, when you close a stream the socket closes. You could flush it instead, and then close it at the end when you're done using it. Glad you're moving forward.

Comment: Yep, instead of close, I shut down the client output.  Done deal, it works like a charm.  Thanks for your patience!